# How to have a group view inside constraint Layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-constraintlayout

I'm really impressed with the way constraint layout works.
Seems like its really easy to place independent views by referring each other for alignment.
But I need to have a card view inside a constrain layout and there will be number of individual views.
Generally I can achieve this with a relative layout inside card view.
But with constraint layout as my root layout,Relative layout inside card view has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are describing -- using a CardView or RelativeLayout inside a ConstraintLayout should work. Which version of Android Studio and ConstraintLayout are you using? could you paste your XML and explain more the problem? Thanks!